# Web server and mail server on same machine?

Tags: web-server, vps, email-server

I just purchased VPS from DigitalOcean and installed LAMP but stuck at mail server. We get 5000+ visits/day and we do sent newsletters to our 10000+ subscribers 2 to 3 times a week and want about 20+ emails for the team members. So is it good to install mail server on the same machine which serves website. Is it cause overload on server ? Do i need to buy two droplets for mail server and web server? I am newbie to VPS and don't know how to install mail server. 
Else is it better to go for managed VPS.

Please guide me in right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: You ***can*** run a mail server and a web server (and a DNS server, and a database server, and a teamspeak server, and...) on one machine if you want. Whether or not this meets your specific needs is something you need to determine.  Note however that sending mailing list/newsletter messages out is probably something you want to use a third-party service for [like Dom suggests](http://serverfault.com/a/525342/32986). MailChimp is one such service, and there are many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send so much mails, use a mailling list server, and speak with the network administrator. You will be considered as a spammer if you try without knowing how send these mails properly. See the mailling lists managers like sympa or majordomo for these features.